# How to save videos from "file:///" to camera roll in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I have a custom Camera that writes captured video to a temporary path that looks like this: `file:///private/var/mobile...`. My question is, how do I save the video to camera roll?

What I have tried:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: videoURL)

    // I've also tried this
    // let exportURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoURL.absoluteString, isDirectory: true)
    // PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFile: exportURL)
}, completionHandler: { success, error in
    if success {
        print("Successful")
    } else if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
})
```

But it always prints: `This operation could not be completed`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked if the user has accepted the PhotoLibraryUsage info plist keys yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as matter of fact you should First of all check the File Extension.if The Extension is not Supported by apple you can not save it in camera roll.you can check the saving Process by trying to save .mp4 file in camera roll to see wether saving process works or not.